# Creating .war files out of a chrome extension possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, war

I'm working on a project that is some kind of a web crawler extension for chrome to create a personal local web archive.
So I am getting videos, images, css-files and script-files with javascript.
The outlines of the project tell me to consider .war-files for saving the crawled pages, but I could not find a way to create .war files out of the extension itself.

Is that even possible or do I have to find another way to save the acquired resources?

Answer (score 0):

Why WAR, of all things? That task is unlikely to be anywhere near easy, as it is Java-specific. Perhaps you need a reminder that [Java and JavaScript are about as similar as Car and Carpet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/934239).

Consider using Chrome API for building [MHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) archives, [`chrome.pageCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture).